# How to add javascript events on FreeMind diagram's nodes?

Tags: freemind

I want to do some validations on FreeMind nodes. Like text should in capital letter or something like that(by validating it via RegEx.) So there is any way to add JavaScript events to nodes(or similar like that)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

FreeMind doesn't support that kind of on-the-fly validation. The best what you could do is to write a Groovy script which performs checks on demand.

With [Freeplane](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeplane/), an improved and active fork of FreeMind you can use [conditional styles](http://freeplane.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Conditional_node_styles) for this purpose. It assigns a visual node style to a node based on the conditions which are evaluated on-the-fly. The conditions can be simple (check for certain text) or arbitrarily complex with script conditions. The conditions can be assigned to a map or to selected nodes.